# Integral of a given complex function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, complex-integration

Consider the following integral with $α,β,γ$ constant coefficients:
\begin{equation}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iαx}}{βx^2+iγx}dx\end{equation}

We can say that this is an inverse Fourier Transformation of a complex function.Can you please propose a way to solve this **analytically or numerically**. Is there any particular theory, books, papers?

Comment: as stated the integral doesn't converges. However it is possible that it had a Cauchy principal value

Comment: How about a numerical approximation?

Comment: With CAS and Cauchy principal value I have:$$\frac{\pi }{\gamma }$$ for: `α > 0, β > 0, γ > 0`

Comment: Can you please assign the whole proof of your method? thanks a lot!